# C++ const_cast operator for multi dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, const-cast

I'm searching for a way in C++11 to encapsulate an overloaded `const_cast` operator for a multi-dimensional array member of a structure / class that defines operations on the member. I've searched on SO, but I can't really find the answer to my problem described below.

Specifically, I'm dealing with a 4x4 matrix defined in a third-party C API as a `typedef` on `double[4][4]`. The API also provides functions using this matrix.

The API looks like the following:

```
typedef double ApiMatrix[4][4];

bool ApiMatrixFunction(ApiMatrix matrix)
{
    // .. some code
    return true;
}
```

I have implemented the structure `MyMatrix` to encapsulate operations on this data type:

```
struct MyMatrix
{
private:
//public:
    double m[4][4];

public:

    MyMatrix() { ... }

    // lots of operations and initialization members
    ....

    // overloading typical calculation operators +,-,*, ....
    ....

    // cast operator to the API data type
    operator ApiMatrix& ()
    {
        return m;
    }
};
```

This works well when using `MyMatrix` as a reference (`MyCodeWithRef`), but it makes trouble to use it as a constant reference (`MyCodeWithConstRef`). Possible workarounds are to duplicate the variable in the function or to give access to the private data and cast it in place by `const_cast<double(*)[4]>(matrix.m)`.

```
// Using MyMatrix reference
void MyCodeWithRef(MyMatrix& matrix)
{
    ApiMatrixFunction(matrix);
}

// Using MyMatrix constant reference
void MyCodeWithConstRef(const MyMatrix& matrix)
{

    // Unfortunately, this fails
    ApiMatrixFunction(matrix);

    // workaround 1: copy the matrix
    MyMatrix m = matrix;

    // workaround 2: use a cast operator in this function
    // requires access to the private m.
    ApiMatrixFunction(const_cast<double(*)[4]>(matrix.m));
}
```

Both workarounds have obvious disadvantages, and I'm searching for a way to define the `const_cast` operator in the `MyMatrix` structure so I can use the same call for the const and non-const references.

Added due to the comments:

To be more specific on my question, I would like to add a sort of custom `const_cast` operator to `MyMatrix`. Something like the following (which of course doesn't work):

```
operator const ApiMatrix& () const
{
   return const_cast<double(*)[4]>(m);
}
```

Comment: If `MyCodeWithRef` is supposed to take a reference, why are you trying to stuff a const reference in there?

Comment: I dont understand why you think you need to "encapsulate an overloaded const_cast operator". You shouldnt cast constness away unless you know for sure that the object actually isnt const. Strictly speaking your `MyCodeWithConstRef` is broken

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain that ApiMatrixFunction does not change the matrix. But since this is a C-API it does not use const ApiMatrix objects.

I'm trying to use const references in my code to make it more readable.

I'm happy to put it a const cast operator in the code, but it should not access the internal data directly but by this cast operator.

Comment: why do you want to use a const reference, when anyhow you want to cast the const away? Simply dont make it const in the first place

Comment: Again, using const references it is a matter of readability in a large project. The C-API function does not have this technique but putting in abstraction layers around it in C++ should show in the signature if a matrix is going to be changed or not.

Comment: how is using a const reference a matter of readability when in reality it is not const?? I would rather say the exact opposite. Pretending it is const when it isnt makes it quite unreadable. Anybody reading the signature of the method will have wrong expectations and run into serious trouble when passing something that is const

Comment: well... I think now I got your point. You know for sure that the matrix wont change so you can safely cast the const away. Nevertheless I wouldnt do it. Did you consider to simply pass it by value? Then the whole const or non-const issue becomes a non-issue

Comment: @AchimSchön That's what `const_cast` is there for, mostly for legacy API interop like in your case, when you know the function won't change the variable.

Comment: @sharyex You are right and I want to use `const_cast`, but it should not be spread over the source code, but in the class MyMatrix.

Comment: You could also make `m` mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Option A:

```
typedef double ApiMatrix[4][4];

class Matrix {
    ApiMatrix a;
public:
    operator ApiMatrix&() const {
        return const_cast<ApiMatrix&>(a);
    }
};

bool ApiMatrixFunction(ApiMatrix matrix)
{
    // .. some code
    return true;
}

// Using MyMatrix reference
void MyCodeWithRef(Matrix& matrix)
{
    ApiMatrixFunction(matrix);
}

// Using MyMatrix constant reference
void MyCodeWithConstRef(const Matrix& matrix)
{
    ApiMatrixFunction(matrix);
}
```

Option B:

```
typedef double ApiMatrix[4][4];

class Matrix {
    ApiMatrix a;
public:
    operator const ApiMatrix&() const {
        return a;
    }
};

bool ApiMatrixFunction(ApiMatrix matrix)
{
    // .. some code
    return true;
}

// Using MyMatrix reference
void MyCodeWithRef(Matrix& matrix)
{
    const ApiMatrix& a = matrix;
    ApiMatrixFunction(const_cast<ApiMatrix&>(a));
}

// Using MyMatrix constant reference
void MyCodeWithConstRef(const Matrix& matrix)
{
    const ApiMatrix& a = matrix;
    ApiMatrixFunction(const_cast<ApiMatrix&>(a));
}
```

Comment: The `const_cast` on a `double [4][4]` does not work for me (C++11, VIsualStudio 2010). I'm not sure if this is something which works for a newer C++ standard or if this is a compiler bug.

Comment: The error comes in German language my translation might not match exactly the english output:

"Conversion of Parameter 1 from Matrix in double [][4] not possible. No user defined Conversion operator which could do the conversion or the operator can not be called"

Comment: operator const ApiMatrix& () const
{
   return const_cast<double(*)[4]>(m);
} body returns ApiMatrix& and operator expect const ApiMatrix&) just remove const in return type)

Comment: I am not familiar with this syntax: `operator ApiMatrix&() const` from option A and this syntax `operator const ApiMatrix&() const` from option B. Is this valid? I am having trouble finding it on the internet. What does it do?